# If $E[X(t)X(s)]=t \land s $.Show that this process has independent increments

Tags: probability, expected-value, gaussian-process

Let $X(t), t\ge0$ be a real-valued Gaussian process with mean zero and
covariance function $E[X(t)X(s)]=t \land s $.Show that this process has independent
increments.

Comment: This looks like a homework (or similar) problem. Add the self-study tag, see http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info, and add your own thoughts on the problem. For example, do you know the definition of 'independent increments' and have you attempted anything?

Comment: Because the process is Gaussian, it will suffice to show that the covariance of two separate increments is zero.  To show this, apply your formula for the covariance.